# Grouping data based on time interval

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, grouping

I have to group a dataset with multiple participants. The participants work a specific time on a specific tablet. If rows are the same tablet, and the time difference between consecutive rows is no more than 10 minutes, the rows belong to one participant. I would like to create a new column ("Participant") that numbers the participants. I know some python but this goes over my head. Thanks a lot!

Dataframe:

```
ID, Time, Tablet
1, 9:12, a
2, 9:14, a
3, 9:17, a
4, 9:45, a
5, 9:49, a
6, 9:51, a
7, 9:13, b 
8, 9:15, b
...
```

Goal:

```
ID, Time, Tablet, Participant
1, 9:12, a, 1
2, 9:14, a, 1
3, 9:17, a, 1
4, 9:45, a, 2
5, 9:49, a, 2
6, 9:51, a, 2
7, 9:13, b, 3
8, 9:15, b, 3
...
```

Comment: Hey @Olivier ! Welcome on StackOverflow ! You should know that Stack Overflow is not for others to write code for you but instead to get help based on what you already did. If you have some code you wrote, you can edit your post to add it. However you may find someone eager to help you as I understand you're not very experienced with Python.

Comment: You can use groupby and cumsum.
`df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])`
`df['time_diff']=df.groupby(['tablet'])['time'].diff().dt.seconds/60`
`df['participant'] = np.where((df['time_diff'].isnull()) | (df['time_diff']>10),  1,0).cumsum()`
Please make sure your time is in datetime format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can groupby first then do a cumsum to get the participant column the way you want. Please make sure the time column is in datetime format and also sort it before you do this.

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time']) 
df['time_diff']=df.groupby(['tablet'])['time'].diff().dt.seconds/60 
df['participant'] = np.where((df['time_diff'].isnull()) | (df['time_diff']>10), 1,0).cumsum()
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar before, I used a combination of a group_by statement and using the Pandas shift function.

```
df = df.sort_values(["Tablet", "Time"])
df["Time_Period"] = df.groupby("Tablet")["Time"].shift(-1)-df["Time"]
df["Time_Period"] = df["Time_Period"].dt.total_seconds()
df["New_Participant"] = df["Time_Period"] > 10*60 #10 Minutes
df["Participant_ID"] = df["New_Participant"].cumsum()
```

Basically I flag every time there is a gap of over 10 minutes between sessions, then do a rolling sum to give each participant a unique ID